# Jquery toggle table when clicking outside and on link

Tags: jquery, toggle

This has probably been solved before but I couldn't find the exact case. I have this button which, upon click, toggles a table. However, I also have a handler for a click outside the div to close it. And so now when a user clicks on the link, the toggle event isn't firing anymore.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zL2wb/1/)

```
<div style="width:110px;">
    <a class="zui-sel-wrapper" id="EQA">
    <span class="zui-sel-def" id="attr-val">Toggle</span>
    <span class="zui-sel-arr">&darr;</span>
    </a>
</div>

<table id="EQAtbl" width="340" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Alpha</td>
    <td>Bravo</td>
    <td>Charly</td>
    </tr>
</table>


$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if ($("#EQAtbl").has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('#EQA').removeClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
        $("#EQAtbl").hide();
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#EQA').click(function(){
        $('#EQAtbl').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
    });

    $('#EQA').blur(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
    });
});​
```

Comment: your fiddle is incomplete... it doesn't include any js, or the div in question.

Comment: my bad, I meant the table (`#EQAtbl`) rather than div and fiddle is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).has("#attr-val").length > 0) { //<-- you had wrong logic here
        $('#EQA').removeClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
        $("#EQAtbl").hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fAtL2/

Answer (score 1):

It's because your logic is contradicting.

In your mouseup

```
if ($("#EQAtbl").has(e.target).length === 0) { // hide
```

but in your click toggling it back so of course it doesn't toggle.. that span is not in your table.. so it hides it.. then it toggles back in the click event

```
$('#EQA').click(function(){
    $('#EQAtbl').toggle();
   $(this).toggleClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
});
```

You can add a check

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) { 
    if ($("#EQAtbl").has(e.target).length === 0 && !$('#EQA').has(e.target).length > 0) {
        $('#EQA').removeClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
        $("#EQAtbl").hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LuRKX/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is .. you have set the **visibility: hidden** to the table..

`.toggle()`  will **show/hide** the div.. It won't have any effect on `visibility:hidden ;`

`.blur()`  will only work for input elements .. Will not have any effect on anchor

Move your mouseOver code inside DOM Ready...  And use **.on()**  to attach the events

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#EQA').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        $('#EQAtbl').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
    });

    $('#EQA').on('blur', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        if ($("#EQAtbl").has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $('#EQA').removeClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
            $("#EQAtbl").hide();
        }
    });
});​
```

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zL2wb/3/)

Comment: I might have not saved the latest version of my fiddle where I removed the visibility:hidden. The problem remains though that a click on the anchor isn't triggering

Comment: Just tried, a click on the link isn't closing the table again. Only able to by clicking outside.

Comment: That's is happening because of the mouseup function.. Whenever you click on the link  the mouseup event fires and hides the div and the toggle shows it again.. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zL2wb/6/  ..I have placed alerts in both the events... Try running it and you will understand what exactly is happening

Answer (score 0):

you mean this : [yourJSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yosafatade/zL2wb/2/) ? try to edit your `visibility: hidden` in your css

Comment: In your example, a click outside the table doesn't close it which is what I'm hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

i would say,dont use toggle simply for the sake of simiplity jquery is providing it with.Define your own toggle functionality is always the better because some times (as also in your case) we want toggle to follow more human logic way.

```
  $('#EQA').click(function(){
        //if this.hide then set this.show
        //if this.show then set this.hide
        //class can be toggled by use of hasClass method
         //this.hasClass then remove else add
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nKAT/1/). I think the code is pretty much self-explanatory.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if ($("#EQAtbl").has(e.target).length === 0 && $("#EQA").has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $('#EQA').removeClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
            $("#EQAtbl").hide();
            $("#EQAtbl").removeClass('shown');
        }
    });

    $('#EQA').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('zui-sel-state-focus');
        if ($("#EQAtbl").hasClass('shown')){
            $('#EQAtbl').hide();
            $("#EQAtbl").removeClass('shown');
        }
        else{
            $('#EQAtbl').show();
            $("#EQAtbl").addClass('shown');
        }
    });

});​
```